# trying to filter string with <br> tags using explode, does not work

Tags: php, html, string, explode

I get a string that looks like this

```
<br>
ACCEPT:YES
<br>
SMMD:tv240245ce
<br>
```

is  contained in a variable $_session['result']

I am trying to parse through this string and get the following either in an array or as separate variables

1. ACCEPT:YES
2. tv240245ce

I first tried

to explode the string using 
 as the delimiter, and that did not work

then I already tried

```
$yes = explode(":", strip_tags($_SESSION['result']));
echo print_r($yes);
```

which gives me an array like so

```
Array ( [0] => ACCEPT [1] => YESSEED [2] => tv240245ce ) 1
```

which gives me one of my answers.

Please what would be a great way of trying to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

is there a way to get rid of the first and last?
then use the remaining one as a delimiter to explode the string ?

or what's the best way to go about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$data=preg_split('/\s?<br>\s?/', str_replace('SMMD:','',$data), NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

See example here:
[CodePad](http://codepad.org/KvRXiOfw)

Comment: Thank you Very much.  So in the future i need to learn how to use regex to be able to handle similar situation ?

Comment: RegEx looks difficult at first, but it's easy once you get the hang of it. `\s` means any whitespace (space, linebreak, tab, etc.) `?` means this may or may not be present, and `<br>` is just `<br>`. The forward slashes are just to mark the beginning and end of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can also skip caring about the spurious `<br>` and treat the whole string as `key:value` format with a simple regex like:

```
 preg_match_all('/^(\w+):(.*)/', $text, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

This requires that you really have line breaks in it though. Gives you a `$result` list which is easy to convert into an associative array afterwards:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => ACCEPT:YES
        [1] => ACCEPT
        [2] => YES
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => SMMD:tv240245ce
        [1] => SMMD
        [2] => tv240245ce
    )
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes your solution is also another answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

First, do a str_replace to remove all instances of "SMMD:". Then, Explode on "< b r >\n". Sorry for weird spaced, it was encoding the line break.
Include the new line character and you should get the array you want:

```
 $mystr = str_replace( 'SMMD:', '', $mystr );
 $res_array = explode( "<br>\n", $mystr );
```

Comment: Wow, Unbelievable speed in response, and right to the point. Thank you.

Comment: No offense, but this won't work on the removing the last `<br>` since it is not followed by a linebreak, and it will give you empty array elements. For reliable results preg_split with `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` should be used.

Comment: oops spoke to soon,  it didnt work , But thanks anyways i really appreciate your time and effort.